# Hadoop grouping by key done wrong

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Here is my code

```
public class SJob {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
{ 
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(SJob.class);
    job.setJobName("SJob");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/WORK/input/data.csv"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/WORK/output"));

    job.setMapperClass(SMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(SReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

 }

}

public class SMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

 @Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();
    String parts[] = line.split(";");

    context.write(new Text(parts[0]), new Text(parts[1]));
 }


}

public class SReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

 @Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String properties = "";

    int noOfElements = 0;

    for(Text value : values)
    {
        properties += value + " ";
        noOfElements++;
    }

    properties += "  " + noOfElements;

        context.write(key, new Text(properties));

 }

}
```

Here is my input file

> 1;a
>
> 2;a
>
> 3;a
>
> 4;a
>
> 1;b
>
> 2;b
>
> 3;b
>
> 4;b
>
> 1;c
>
> 2;c
>
> 3;c
>
> 4;c

Here is my output file

> 1 b c   2
>
> 2 a b c   3
>
> 3 a b c   3
>
> 4 a b c   3
>
> 1 a   1

As you can see, the grouping by key is performed poorly, the output should be

> 1 a b c   3
>
> 2 a b c   3
>
> 3 a b c   3
>
> 4 a b c   3

It looks that somehow there is a problem with processing the first row, I trying swapping the first and the second row, and then the same thing happens, in that case instead of

> 2 a b c 3
>
> I get
>
> 2 b c 2
>
> 2 a 1

What could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe you have some whitespaces in the beginning of the file? Try to trim your input lines: `String line = value.toString().trim();`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, the same thing happens, I tried now. It is really strange that it happens with the first line, all the others are grouped fine... Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, i have a few theories. Maybe you're mixing `mapred` and `mapreduce` packages in import? Did you try to use `TextInputFormat` instead of `FileInputFormat`?

Comment: Checked both things, mapreduce is always used, tried with TextInputFormat, same thing happens. More theories?

Comment: I didn't find any mistakes in your code. The last thing i can suggest: try to set `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);` and `job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);`.

Comment: I have added that, but no luck. Thanks for your effort, it's really annoying, since its basic stuff... I have followed some examples and code is completely the same and my file input doesn't seem so special...

Comment: Maybe I should add that, as you can see from my example, the first line somehow always gets last in the output file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I have used Hadoop 0.20.2 because of certain limitations. The thing is that there is a bug in Hadoop that has been resolved in some versions, but not in the one I used.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5777

This version does not work well with UTF-8 files. The file needs to be saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

After correcting this everything works as expected.